# How to make css not apply to certain attributes?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a plugin for a wordpress page and in the theme it's going in, there is a style.css for that theme. In that style.css there are CSS attributes that apply to all img and p tags and that is messing up the appearance of my plugin. How can I make it so my plugin, which has its own stylesheet, ignore the style of the theme's css?

Answer (score 1):

Include your stylesheet **after** the style.css

So:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/yourStylesheet.css">
```

If this still is not working use `!important`, but try to avoid this.

`!important` is placed after the style rule, like so:

```
p {
    color: red !important;
}
```

You can also use more specific styles like @SarahBourt said.

```
#news-item > p {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure this is the case. Because I have a plugin, which registers the stylesheet and adds the stylesheet to the plugin. And this is ontop of the page itself, which already has the theme loaded?

Comment: You can also use more specific styles ( .containerClass > p ) and individual overrides with !important.  like p {  font-weight: bold !important;  }

Comment: im not downvoting, but i will try the specific style

Comment: the specific styling kind of worked...its not perfect but at least the img isn't overlapping the rest of the div

Comment: @albert, okay, did you succeed in adding the stylesheet after the style.css?

Comment: Its wordpress so I don't just add the css at the head of the html file or w.e, I have to register and enqueue it using wordpress functions, and the theme already has its own css...and my plugin has its own css. im sure I could find out what order its in, but im pretty sure the theme loads its css first

Comment: @albert, okay I understand, the CSS should work than. use the exact same css anchor/rule as the style.css and everything should be working fine. So if style.css has `#news-item .item { color: red }` overwrite it with exactly the same: `#news-item .item { color: blue; }`

Answer (score 0):

Craete a new `CSS` file and include your stylesheet after the default `bootstrap` css file, your styles will override the bootstrap styles

If still you are getting some problems you can also use `!important` next to that style

`!important` will ensure that your style will be given first preference

**Ex:**

```
p{
display:inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, i don't use any styles for img and p tags, I just use IDs. So it wouldn't override them cause there are no styles for it. Also, the default style.css for the theme uses !important around some of its img tags as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can place styles in your stylesheet specifically to override the theme's styles.

Assuming your stylesheet *is* loading after the default theme stylesheet, then you can do the following.

In your web inspector, find the offending style in the theme's stylesheet. Copy it into your stylesheet, and replace every value with ['initial'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) to reset it to the defaults, or with your custom styles if that's more appropriate.

If your stylesheet is loading *before* the theme's styles, then you can still override the theme styles, even if they include `!important.` To override `!important,` create a more specific selector than the theme uses (Read about [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to figure out the best way of doing this), and add `!important` only to those which have `!important` in the theme style. If the style you're overriding doesn't use `!important,` just use the more specific style, as including too many `!important` tags can make it harder for you or someone else to modify your code later, as you're experiencing now.

In addition, you want to be sure that your overrides *only* get applied to your plugin, and not the rest of the site. So, wrap the plugin with a `div` or other element if it isn't already, and give the wrapper a unique class or id, e.g. `class="my-plugin"`. Preface all of your overrides with this class to avoid breaking other areas of the site.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-plugin>
    <!--plugin HTML-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-plugin img {
   //override styles
}
.my-plugin p {
   //override styles
}
```

Overriding original styling like this can get messy, but sometimes it's the only way to get things done when you don't have access to the other .css files. Just do the minimum necessary to make your styles more specific and you should be okay.